# Как объединить datetimepicker и мой код jquery?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Поставил datetimepicker на свой bootstrap 3 отсюда - https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Вот мой код:

Инициализация datetimepicker:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            pickTime: false,
            language: 'ru',
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        });
    });
});
```

Input:

```html
<input class="form-control" required type="text" name="date" id="datetimepicker1" value="<?=$row[date]?>">
```

И это работает до тех пока я не добавлю следующий код между инициализацией и INPUT'ом (тогда datetimepicker перестаёт работать). Вот так:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('input[name=date][type=text]').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // поле "дата" после загрузки страницы с атрибутом disabled
})

$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#perenos').click(function() { // клик по чекбоксу
        if ($('#perenos').is(':checked')) { // если выбран чекбокс "Перенос" атрибуты disabled убрать  
            $('input[name=date]').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        if (!$('#perenos').is(':checked')) { // если не выбран чекбокс "Перенос" атрибуты disabled включить   
            $('input[name=date][type=text]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: ошибки в консоли браузера проверьте

Comment: и собстенно, что значит перестает работать? вы дизейблите инпут, понятно дело, что клик в него больше не будет открывать окошко пикера. Что не так то, опишите.

Comment: teran, input изначально задисейблен (первый фрагмент кода). При клике  по #perenos я атрибут дисейбл убираю (третий фрагмент кода), но окошко пикера не открывается больше

Comment: еще как доп вопрос. почему изначально дизаеблите инпут в ready,а не просто пропишите атрибут в коде инпута. Зачем обращаетесь через `inpit[name][type]` если увас есть `#datetimepicker1`. Почему вообще у него такой id, если вы не используете в  нем time-часть. Зачем в последней функции у вас написано `if()`, а вместо `else` у вас тот же иф с обратным условием. Зачем вы вообще все это разбиваете на разные `ready` функции. И да,  в подключении что-то то не то. у вас там двойной вызов ready

Comment: teran, 1. Прописывание атрибута в коде не решает проблемы, ничего не меняется. 2. Просто когда писал код - пришла в голову идея писать именно так. Кажется ошибок нет, которые могут повлиять на работоспособность кода. Я только учусь кодить. Если решения в этом посте не найду - приведу код в порядок, чтобы код был читабельный, и буду снова искать решение, спасибо, что указали на ошибки, teran

Answer (score 0):

1) `$('#datetimepicker1')` можно сохранить в переменную, чтобы не искать его каждый раз.
2) Проверку чекбокса можно упростить до `if-else`.
3) Нет смысла использовать конструкцию `$('document').ready(function() { $(function() { ... }); });`

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  var datetimepicker1 = $('#datetimepicker1');

  datetimepicker1.datetimepicker({
    locale: 'ru',
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
  });

  $('#perenos').click(function() { // клик по чекбоксу
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) { // если выбран чекбокс "Перенос" атрибуты disabled убрать  
      datetimepicker1.removeAttr("disabled");
    } else { // если не выбран чекбокс "Перенос" атрибуты disabled включить   
      datetimepicker1.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input id="perenos" type="checkbox" />
<input class="form-control" required type="text" name="date" id="datetimepicker1" disabled value="" />
```

Comment: У меня не срабатывает событие при клике по #perenos. Зато срабатывает, если оборачиваю всё это в $('document').ready(function() { ... }) - но так окно datetimepicker не появляется. Что у меня может быть не так?

Comment: Оборачивайте в `$('document').ready(function() {`, долно всегда работать нормально (поправил в сниппете). Не срабатывать может при условии, что код с `document.ready` стоит выше, чем подключение jQuery.